# How to replace all values in a dataframe with their respective value in column X?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(NA, 5, 5),
  B = c(5, NA, NA),
  C = c(5, 5, NA),
  X = c(0.5, 0.25, 0.8)
)
```

How would I go about replacing all the values of 5 with their respective value in column X? Ideally I'd like to use a `dplyr` command if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `across` -

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(A:C, ~ifelse(. == 5, X, .)))

#     A   B    C    X
#1   NA 0.5 0.50 0.50
#2 0.25  NA 0.25 0.25
#3 0.80  NA   NA 0.80
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(A:C, ~ case_when(. == 5 ~ X,
                                 TRUE ~ .)))

     A   B    C    X
1   NA 0.5 0.50 0.50
2 0.25  NA 0.25 0.25
3 0.80  NA   NA 0.80
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x==5, df$X, x))
df
     A   B    C    X
1   NA 0.5 0.50 0.50
2 0.25  NA 0.25 0.25
3 0.80  NA   NA 0.80
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     mutate(across(A:C, ~ replace(., .  %in% 5, X[. %in% 5])))
     A   B    C    X
1   NA 0.5 0.50 0.50
2 0.25  NA 0.25 0.25
3 0.80  NA   NA 0.80
```